# Grails 3 with Spring-Security-Core 3.0.3 plugin servlet filter ordering with filterChain when filters set to 'none'

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

I've been tasked with upgrading some legacy Grails 2.x apps to Grails 3.0.14. Since the apps used the Spring-Security-Core plugin, I've upgraded that to 3.0.3. However, I quite frequently stumble across inaccessible static assets that give this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There was a problem retrieving the current GrailsWebRequest. This usually indicates a filter ordering issue (the 'springSecurityFilterChain' filter-mapping element must be positioned after the 'grailsWebRequest' element when using @Secured annotations).
```

I do not have any defined FilterRegistrationBean, I am not using SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter, and there is no web.xml, so I'm not sure how the apps could be altering the default servlet filter order to cause this problem.

The only difference appears to be in my application.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS']
]
```

If I remove the filters: 'none' line, everything works.
I know that in Java applications, Spring Security 3.1.x deprecated filters = "none", and in more modern versions it is unsupported completely. Is that what is causing this strange error message?

Comment: can you provide the urlmapping?